# Getting error when converting python to exe (because of folium library)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Here is my Python code, which simply generates a map into a .html file using **Folium** module. As expected, the code doesn't return any error.

```
import folium
m = folium.Map(location=[39.3999, 8.2245], tiles='cartodbpositron', zoom_start=3)       
m.save('output.html')
```

However when I convert the python code to .exe file, I get the following error when I want to execute the .exe file:

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/nade/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "folium/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/nade/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "branca/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "/home/nade/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "branca/colormap.py", line 20, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/_MEIS1K8Tv/branca/_cnames.json'
[17356] Failed to execute script test
```

I have used **Pyinstaller** to convert the python to .exe, here is the command I used (I used auto-py-to-exe for more specific convertion):

`pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed --icon "/path/to/icon" --key "encryption-key-value"  "/path/to/script"`

I have realised that this happens only because of **Folium** library. How do I make this module compatible when converting to .exe?

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and found a workaround for this issue.
The solution based on this site: `https://www.tutorialfor.com/questions-153381.htm`

First, you need to modify these 3 files:

1. \folium\folium.py
2. \folium\raster_layers.py
3. \branca\element.py

Change the line `ENV = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('folium', 'templates'))` to below both 3 files.

```
#ENV = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('folium', 'templates'))
import os, sys
from jinja2 import FileSystemLoader
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # we are running in a bundle
    templatedir = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    # we are running in a normal Python environment
    templatedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
ENV = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(templatedir + '\\templates'))
```

After that, you need to edit the `.spec` file. Open the spec file and add `datas` section the below lines.

```
...
             binaries=[],
             datas=[
                (".\\env\\Lib\\site-packages\\branca", "branca"),
                (".\\env\\Lib\\site-packages\\branca\\*.json","branca"),
                (".\\env\\Lib\\site-packages\\branca\\templates", "templates"),
                (".\\env\\Lib\\site-packages\\folium\\templates", "templates"),
             ],
             hiddenimports=[],
...
```

Then build using spec file.

```
pyinstaller <script_name>.spec
```